# How does the recursion work when decompressing an RLE string with (embedded) parantheses?

Tags: java, recursion, compression

I need to write a code that decompresses RLE strings, such as

2a4b --> aabbbb

2(a2(bc)4d) --> abcbcddddabcbcdddd

2(a)2(b) --> aabb

Right now my code decompresses correctly for the most part, but I still have some parantheses problems that I can't seem to solve.

I have a for loop that goes through the string and checks every character.

if the character is a '(' :

```
            String substring = decompress(sequence.substring(i+1));

            if (count == 0) {
                count = 1;
            }
            while (count >0){
                reststring.append(substring);
                count--;
                number_count = 0;
            }

            string.append(reststring);

            int counting_open = 0;
            int counting_closed = 0;
            int count_loops = 0;

            for(int j = i; j<sequence.length(); j++){
                if(sequence.charAt(j) == '(') {
                    counting_open += 1;
                }

                else if(sequence.charAt(j) == ')'){
                    break;
                }
            }

            for(int j = i; j<sequence.length(); j++){
                count_loops +=1;
                if(sequence.charAt(j) == ')') {
                    counting_closed += 1;
                    if(counting_open == counting_closed){
                        i = j;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                else if (count_loops == sequence.length()-1){
                    return string.toString();
                }
            }
```

It still works with strings such as:

2(2(ab)ef2(hi)) or 2(ab2(c)e)

Now my problem comes with strings such as:

3(2a3(ab)2(ba)2b)

Expected output: aaabababbababbaaabababbababbaaabababbababb

My output: aaabababbababbaaabababbababbaaabababbababbbb

The 2b repeats itself after the decompression should already be done and I don't know how to fix this problem properly without causing an issue elsewhere.

Is it even possible to solve this assignment this way or should i start over with a different approach?

Comment: `2(a2(bc)4d) --> abcbcdddd` should be `2(a2(bc)4d) --> abcbcddddabcbcdddd`.

Comment: Your method doesn't seem to be recursive or at least some parts contradict that, e.g. `counting_open += 1;`. Basically you'd parse the string normally and whenever you encounter an opening paranthesis (`(`) you call the method recursively and leave it when you hit a closing paranthesis (`)`) or the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't recursive from what I can see.
I wrote some pseudo code, so don't expect it to work perfectly but this is how it should look like IMO:

```java
String recursive(String s) {
  String result = "";
  for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    char c = s.charAt(i);
    if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
      // Search for the closing parantheses index
      int endIndex = getSubStringIndex(s, i);
      String subStringResult = recursive(s.substring(i + 1, endIndex));
      // Multiply the result of recursive substring
      for (int repeatIndex = 0; repeatIndex < Character.getNumericValue(c); repeatIndex++) {
        result += subStringResult;
      }
      i = endIndex;
    } 
    else {
      result += c;
    }
  }
  return result;
}



// From index should be the position of '(' character
int getSubStringIndex(String s, int fromIndex) {
  int index = fromIndex + 1;
  int newOpeningCounter = 0;
  // Search for the index 
  while (index < s.length()) {
    char c = s.charAt(index);
    if (c == '(') {
      newOpeningCounter++;
    }
    else if (c == ')') {
       // If there aren't any new opening parantheses, exit the while
       if (newOpeningCounter == 0) {
          return index;
       }
       // Else the the ')' we found is matching another new '(' we found in the way
       // So we decrease the counter to show the parantheses are closed
       else {
          newOpeningCounter--;
       }
    }

     index++;
  }

   // TODO: handle error
   return null;
}
```

notice the call to `recursive` method inside itself which makes the code recursive

Comment: Your getSubStringIndex() really helped me, and now it works! Thank you!!